# Weird operator precedence while slicing dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I'll get right to the code, let's take a simple dataframe:

```
a <- c(10,20,30,40)
b <- c('book', 'pen', 'textbook', 'pencil_case')
c <- c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE)
d <- c(2.5, 8, 10, 7)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)
df
   a           b     c    d
1 10        book  TRUE  2.5
2 20         pen FALSE  8.0
3 30    textbook  TRUE 10.0
4 40 pencil_case FALSE  7.0
```

Now I wanna extract the first 3 rows but I won't use `df[1:3,]`, instead I'll use `df[1:1*3,]`. But apparently it's not the same because the output of the latter is:

```
   a        b    c  d
3 30 textbook TRUE 10
```

Could someone explain what's happening? Doesn't the multiplication have precedence?

Comment: They are not the same: ```1:1*3``` if you run this you'll get `3`. That's because **`:`** gets evaluated first. If you want to get the same results you should use: `df[1:(1*3),]`

Comment: Operator precedence is listed in `?Syntax` if you're curious.

Comment: @M-- So `1:1` generate a list with a single 1, and then it's multiplied by 3 yielding 3

Answer (score 1):

As per comments, `1:1` generates a list with a single 1, and then it's multiplied by 3 yielding 3. Mistery solved. I know it sounds trivial now, but the bug in my code involved a more complex expression as index.